# How to print the contents of a register in emu8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-registers, emu8086

```
include 'emu8086.inc'
#make_com#

org 100h

s1 dw 50,60,70,80,90,100,120,130,140,160,170,190,190,220,250,270,300

    MOV SI,0
    MOV CX,16

s2:
    MOV AX,s1[SI]

s3:
    INC SI
    CMP AX,100
    JBE s4
    JA s5

s4:
    PRINTf AX
    JMP s3

s5:
    CMP AX,200
    JB s6
    JA s7

s6:
    PRINTf AX
    JMP s3

s7:
    PRINTf AX
    JMP s3

    END
    ;printf AX doesn't work and i want to print the contents of AX
```

Comment: You have to convert it to string, then you display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ;printf AX doesn't work and i want to print the contents of AX

You haven't shown us what *PRINTf* is supposed to do. So all of your `PRINTf AX` macro calls could be OK.

But your program does have 2 errors that prevent it from executing correctly.

1. A .COM program starts executing from the top but that's where you have placed your data. This must not be executed! So either place the data below the code or jump over the data.
2. The data you use is word sized and thus you need to add 2 to the SI register when iterating over the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can display AX as is, but you will see weird characters on screen. A procedure to convert from binary (AX) to string is necessary. Next code puts a number into AX, converts AX to string, and displays the string. You can use the procedure **number2string** for your future programs. Copy-paste next code in EMU8086 and run it :

```
.stack 100h
;------------------------------------------
.data
str db 6 dup('$') ;STRING TO STORE NUMBER. 
;------------------------------------------
.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;CONVERT NUMBER TO STRING.
  mov  ax, 10382      ;ANY NUMBER.
  call number2string  ;CONVERT AX. RESULT IN "STR".

;DISPLAY STRING.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset str  ;NUMBER CONVERTED.
  int  21h

;WAIT FOR USER TO PRESS ANY KEY.
  mov  ah,7
  int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h           

;------------------------------------------

;NUMBER TO CONVERT MUST ENTER IN AX.
;ALGORITHM : EXTRACT DIGITS ONE BY ONE, STORE
;THEM IN STACK, THEN EXTRACT THEM IN REVERSE
;ORDER TO CONSTRUCT STRING.

proc number2string
  mov  bx, 10 ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  mov  cx, 0 ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
cycle1:       
  mov  dx, 0 ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  div  bx ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  push dx ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  inc  cx ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  cmp  ax, 0  ;IF NUMBER IS
  jne  cycle1 ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
  mov  si, offset str
cycle2:  
  pop  dx        
  add  dl, 48 ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  mov  [ si ], dl
  inc  si
  loop cycle2  

  ret
endp
```

A little more explanation : for your future programs, the procedure **number2string** requires a variable in data segment named "str". As you see on the code, "str" has length 6, because AX can hold a number of 5 digits or less, and, if you want to display it, strings require '$' sign, that's why length is 6. The parameter for **number2string** must be placed on AX. Of course, you can change the variable name (str) and the register used (AX).

Answer (score 0):

This will print all registers to screen. Hope this is what you are looking for. you could save it as macro or globally and call it anytime to print all registers.

```
    org 100h
    jmp start
    
        vec1    db ?   
        alreg   db "AL = $" 
        ahreg   db "AH = $"
        blreg   db "BL = $"
        bhreg   db "BH = $"
        clreg   db "CL = $"
        chreg   db "CH = $"
        dlreg   db "DL = $"
        dhreg   db "DH = $"   
    start:   ;--------------first we do al register------
            mov cx, 8
            mov vec1, al 
            
            lea dx, alreg
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h
            
            call f1        
       
            ;----now doing ah------- 2
            
            mov vec1, ah 
            
            lea dx, ahreg
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h
            
            call f1 
            
            ;---now doing bl---------3
            
            
            mov vec1, bl 
            
            lea dx, blreg
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h
            
            call f1
            
            
            ;---now doing bh---------4
            
            mov vec1, bh
            
            lea dx, bhreg
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h
            
            call f1
            
            ;---now doing cl---------5
            
            mov vec1, cl
            
            lea dx, clreg
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h
            
            call f1
            
            ;---now doing ch---------6
            
            mov vec1, ch
            
            lea dx, chreg
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h
            
            call f1
            
            ;---now doing dl---------7
            
            mov vec1, dl
            
            lea dx, dlreg
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h
            
            call f1
            
            
            ;---now doing dh---------8
            
            mov vec1, dh
            
            lea dx, dhreg
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h
            
            call f1     
            call end:
            ;--------------------------done-----
            
             f1 proc
            lea si, vec1 ;load vec1 address to si
            mov al, [si] ;mov content of mem addr pointed by si
            push cx      ;save counter
            mov cx, 2    ;set new counter to work on 2 charcters
                        
            leftnibble:  ;start with left nibble first
            shr al, 4    ;shif right 4x to mov left nibble to right
            push ax      ;save ax before int 21h
            
            mov bl, 0ah  ;mov 10 dec in bl to cmp with al
            cmp al, bl   ;three jmp operations based on zero and carry flag to
                         ;follow. 
            jz printchar  ;jump if zero flag set to 1
            jc printdigit ;jump if carry flag set to 1. des<source.
            jnc printchar ;jmp no carry = des>source           
                          ;right nibble convert operation:
            rightnibble:      
            mov ax, 0     ;zero ax incase leftovers
            mov al, [si]  ;mov content of mem addr pointed by si
            pop bx        ;retrun saved char 
            shl bx, 4     ;shit left 4x moving right nibble to lef.
    
            xor ax, bx    ;clear left nibble to zero           
            mov bl, 0ah   ;set 0ah (10 decimal) to bl to cmp
            cmp al, bl
            jz printchar  ;jump if zero flag set to 1
            jc printdigit ;jump if carry flag set to 1. des<source.
            jnc printchar ;jmp no carry = des>source             
                     
            printdigit:       ;print if any of the charcters is 9 or less
           
            mov dl, al    
            add dl, 30h   ;add 30 hex to convert to ascii
            mov ah, 06h   ; echo to monitor service
            int 21h
                    
            dec cx        ;dec counter 
            jcxz tab      ; jmp if cx is zero
            jmp rightnibble ;go process right side nibble
                    
            printchar:        ;same as printdigit only for letter A-F
            mov dl, al
            add dl, 37h   ;convert A,B,C,D,E or F to ascii
            mov ah, 06h   ;print character function 06h
            int 21h
            
            dec cx         
            jcxz tab
            jmp rightnibble  
    
            tab:
            mov dl, 32    ;ascii #32 is tab
            mov ah, 06
            int 21h
            int 21h       ;inserting 2 tab spaces
            pop cx        ;return counter set initially to 8 at start.
            dec cx
            jcxz end        
            ret
            f1 endp
            
    ;---------------------------   
            
    end:
        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
```